# Kafka transaction timeout vs transaction id expiration

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand the difference between the property `(max.)transaction.timeout.ms` and `transaction.id.expiration.timeout`.

From what I understand, the former kills a transaction if the producer does not send an update within its timeout (default 60 seconds), while the latter kills the producer transaction id if it does not send an update within its timeout (default 7 days).

My question is: why do both exist and why they have very different default values? I think because if a producer does not send a transaction update, the transaction is killed following the first timeout, and if the producer continues to not send any update, after the second timeout also the producer transaction id is retired. Otherwise I would not understand how the second timeout could happen, since the first one already closes the transaction.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds correct.